# JNDI.What is the thing?

Tags: java, jndi

I read a lot of information about jndi. But I don't understand what is the thing.
All examples based on difficults servers and other.
Can you answer for my questions:

1. What problem does   resolve  by JNDI?
2. What relation doest it has with JDBC?
3. Can you help me to find simple jndi tutorial?
4. How does works JNDI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. JNDI, beasically, is a lookup service. You give it a name, and it returns you an object that has been stored under that name. Its main use is inside application servers, where resources configured in the server (like a transaction manager, a DataSource, software components etc.) are made available to the deployed applications in JNDI.
2. Almost none, except JDBC DataSources are often retrieved from JNDI.
3. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/
4. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/

Comment: Not sure the reason for the down-vote. Negated.